# Kotlin - equivalence to Swift's combination of "if let + cast"

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to find out how to achieve the combination of "if let + cast" in kotlin:

in swift:

```
if let user = getUser() as? User {
   // user is not nil and is an instance of User
}
```

I saw some documentation but they say nothing regarding this combination

https://medium.com/@adinugroho/unwrapping-sort-of-optional-variable-in-kotlin-9bfb640dc709
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

One option is to use a [safe cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) + [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) + [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html):

```
(getUser() as? User)?.let { user ->
    ...
}
```

Another would be to use a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) inside the lambda passed to `let`:

```
getUser().let { user ->
    if (user is User) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But maybe the most readable would be to just introduce a variable and use a smart cast right there:

```
val user = getUser()
if (user is User) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you are using a "safe call" (`?. `) and not the "elvis operator" (`?:`) in your first example.

Comment: Clearly the if let syntax Swift added was genius, these choices are poor and more poor..

Comment: You might need to replace "as?" with "as" to skip use assertion operator !! inside let
(getUser() as? User)?.let { user ->
    user!!  ...
}

might be: 
(getUser() as User)?.let { user ->
    user ...
}

Comment: Contrary to @Rob, I find the Swift syntax to be the poorest option. It requires understanding the concept of an `if` has been overloaded from a boolean check to a nil/optional check and assignment side-effect.

Plus the scope of the assignment looks wrong -- the assignment positioning prior to the opening brace would suggest the assignment is available in the `else` also!

The Kotlin approaches all require no new syntax knowledge over commonly used operators in regular old Kotlin, and at very little to no additional "cost" in extra length over the Swift version.

Comment: BTW, since the introduction of `also` into Kotlin, this is a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850409/430128. The `let` returns the value of the `then` block, so it isn't the same as the Swift idiom, especially not if an `else` is intended on nil via a trailing elvis operator.

Comment: @raman great counter arguments, especially the one about not more characters. If let is so great how come no one ever remembers how to use it? Kotlin is so full of little self-impressed optimizations that their echo chamber liked. Frankly I think optionals in both languages (Swift and Kotlin) are a mess.

Comment: @Rob Well we wouldn't be programmers if we weren't spending at least some of our time alternately bitching about or pimping one language or another :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin can automatically figure out whether a value is nil or not in the current scope based on regular if statements with no need for special syntax.

```
val user = getUser()

if (user != null) {
    // user is known to the compiler here to be non-null
}
```

It works the other way around too

```
val user = getUser()

if (user == null) {
    return
}

// in this scope, the compiler knows that user is not-null 
// so there's no need for any extra checks
user.something
```

Comment: This is an awesome part of Kotlin!

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin you can use the let:

```
val user = getUser()?.let { it as? User } ?: return
```

This solution is closest to guard but it may be useful.

Comment: value must be returned on the other side of ?:

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin you can use:

```
(getUser() as? User)?.let { user ->
  // user is not null and is an instance of User
}
```

`as?` is a ['safe' cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) that returns `null` instead of throwing an error on failure.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?

```
val user = getUser() ?: return
```

Comment: this is good, swift equivalent of a nil coalescing operator.
val value: String = data?.first() ?: "Nothing here."

Comment: this syntax is awful and unlegible. why the heck google just didn't copied whats good ?

Comment: @JBarros35 Google didnt write Kotlin.