# Swift 'if let' statement equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin is there an equivalent to the Swift code below?

```
if let a = b.val {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 492, accepted):

You can use the `let`-function like this:

```
val a = b?.let {
    // If b is not null.
} ?: run {
    // If b is null.
}
```

Note that you need to call the `run` function only if you need a block of code. You can remove the `run`-block if you only have a oneliner after the elvis-operator (`?:`).

Be aware that the `run` block will be evaluated either if `b` is null, or if the `let`-block evaluates to `null`.

Because of this, you usually want just an `if` expression.

```
val a = if (b == null) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

In this case, the `else`-block will only be evaluated if `b` is not null.

Comment: It isn't equivalent. `a` cannot be accessed inside `let` and `run` block.

Comment: `a` isn't defined yet inside the scope of `let` and `run`. But you can access the value of `b` inside the `let` with the implicit parameter `it`. This serves the same purpose I guess.

Comment: The swift code completes the assignment of `a` before those blocks of code. And `a` can be accessed inside.

Comment: What does it assign to `a`? If it's `b`, then `it` serves the exact same purpose. Does it reassign `a` with the result of the `val`-block?

Comment: Then, in kotlin, no assignment is needed?

Comment: You can only access `it` from within the `let` block. The result of the `let` or `run` block will be assigned to `a`. The result is the last expression in the block. You use the assignment _after_ `let`/`run` has finished, just like you do with any other normal assignment.

Comment: This idiom-to-idiom translation is actually wrong. The Swift code doesn't result in the symbol `a` being defined after the `if let` expression, it is defined just for the `then` clause of `if let`.

Comment: Another way these two aren't equivalent is in thread safety. In the second version, if `b` is a property, it can be changed (by another thread) after the null check, but before it is accessed in the block. For this reason, I would recommend either taking a copy of `b` to a local `val` to work on, or to simply use the `let` version.

Comment: Should use `also` instead of `let` or `run` will execute if `let` return null: `b?.let { null } ?: run { /* will always execute */ }`

Comment: @Love That would change the semantics of the statement. The `also` function will return `b` itself if it's not null, not what the lambda returns.

Comment: @marstran Take a look at [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850409/1020871) *note that `a` is bound only within the then-block*.

Comment: @Love Yes, that is what is discussed earlier in this comment chain. This answer is not to be regarded as a one-to-one translation of the Swift code. It is simply how you would express it in Kotlin.

Comment: The reason of existence of `if let` is precisely the scope control it provides. It allows you to capture the result of an optional-typed expression without exporting it to the rest of the function body. This is why an example such as `b?.let ...` doesn't demonstrate its purpose: if you have that in your code, you can just as well write `if (b != null) { ... }` In Swift, if you have `if let b { ... }` you can just as well have `if b != nil { ... }` No language would introduce special syntax just for that.

Comment: Note that the `run` after the elvis operator is not required. You can have a single operation after the elvis operator without a run statement. `?: return` for an instance is perfectly valid.

Comment: @marstran, the last sentence does not make sense. Should it not read "the `else`-block will only be evaluated if `b` is **not** null"?

Comment: poorly implemented optionals example. swift if let construction does not work like that. it creates a new variable with optional unwrapped.

Comment: @JBarros35 As I have explained in the comments above, the answer is not to be regarded as a 1-to-1 translation of the Swift code. It is a translation into idiomatic Kotlin code. The unwrapped variable can be accessed inside the `let`-block with `it`.

Comment: use it else block of let:

inline fun <R> R?.orElse(block: () -> R): R {
    return this ?: block()
}

Comment: This is not the most accurate answer. We should use `also` instead of `let`.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng As I've explained multiple times above, the point of this answer was not to make a 1-to-1 translation of the Swift code, but rather show you would usually handle a nullable-value with idiomatic Kotlin. So saying it's not accurate is a moot point. Using `also` here would just bind `a` to `b` instead of the result of the let-expression. You can just as well do that, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 116):

Let's first ensure we understand the semantics of the provided Swift idiom:

```
if let a = <expr> {
     // then-block
}
else {
     // else-block
}
```

It means this: "if the `<expr>` results in a non-nil optional, enter the `then`-block with the symbol `a` bound to the unwrapped value. Otherwise enter the `else` block.

Especially note that `a` is bound *only within the `then`-block*. In Kotlin you can easily get this by calling

```
<expr>?.also { a ->
    // then-block
}
```

and you can add an `else`-block like this:

```
<expr>?.also { a ->
    // then-block
} ?: run {
    // else-block
}
```

This results in the same semantics as the Swift idiom.

Comment: `also` is the closest match to `if let`, thank you.

Comment: Great answer, as @Leon said, this is the closest to the Swift `if let`. Thank you for the explanation - this should be the accepted answer. `also` should be used rather than the `let`, since Kotlin `let` returns a value... Thanks!

Comment: use it else block of let: inline fun <R> R?.orElse(block: () -> R): R { return this ?: block() }

Comment: Can't we change this to be the accepted answer? "also" is way better then "let" in this case

Answer (score 21):

My answer is totally a copy cat from the others. However, I cannot understand their expression easily. So I guess it would be nice to provide an more understandable answer.

In swift:

```
if let a = b.val {
  //use "a" as unwrapped
}
else {

}
```

In Kotlin:

```
b.val?.let{a -> 
  //use "a" as unwrapped
} ?: run{
  //else case
}
```

Comment: Using `let` instead of `also` means that the `run` block will execute whenever the `let` block returns `null`, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 14):

### `if let` statement

Swift `if let` Optional Binding (so called `if-let` statement) is used to extract a non-optional value if one exists, or to do nothing if a value is `nil`.

Swift's `if-let` statement:

```swift
let b: Int? = 50

if let a: Int = b {
    print("Good news!")
} else {
    print("Equal to 'nil' or not set")
}

/*  RESULT: Good news!  */
```

In Kotlin, like in Swift, to avoid crashes caused by trying to access a null value when it’s not expected, a specific syntax (like `b.let { }` in second example) is provided for properly unwrapping **`nullable types`**:

Kotlin's equivalent1 of Swift's `if-let` statement:

```kotlin
val b: Int? = null
val a = b

if (a != null) { 
    println("Good news!")
} else { 
    println("Equal to 'null' or not set")
}

/*  RESULT: Equal to 'null' or not set  */
```

Kotlin’s `let` method, when used in combination with the safe-call operator `?:`, provides a concise way to handle nullable expressions.

Kotlin's `inline let function` and Elvis Operator of Swift's `nil coalescing operator`:

```kotlin
val b: Int? = null

val a = b.let { nonNullable -> nonNullable } ?: "Equal to 'null' or not set"
println(a)

/*  RESULT: Equal to 'null' or not set  */
```

### `guard let` statement

`guard-let` statement in Swift is simple and powerful. It checks for some condition and if it evaluates to be false, then the `else` statement executes which normally will exit a method.

Let's explore a Swift's `guard-let` statement:

```swift
let b: Int? = nil

func method() {
    guard let a: Int = b else {
        print("Equal to 'nil' or not set")
        return
    }
    print("Good news!")
}
method()

/*  RESULT: Equal to 'nil' or not set  */
```

Kotlin's similar effect of Swift's `guard-let` statement:

Unlike Swift, in Kotlin, there is no **guard** statement at all. However, you can use the `Elvis Operator` – **`?:`** for getting a similar effect.

```kotlin
val b: Int? = 50

fun method() {
    val a = b ?: return println("Equal to 'null' or not set")
    return println("Good news!")
}
method()

/*  RESULT: Good news!  */
```

Comment: it does not unwrap the optional and created another variable based on it. its not a let valid construction.

Comment: Sorry, what construction you mean?

Comment: if let a {} else {} the way you put there you are just executing stuff but there are no variable unwrapped inside to be used! Swift unwraps the variable for programmers and Kotlin its just poor in terms of optionals.

Comment: This also works:
`foo?.let { /* statements here */
} ?: run { 
    /* statements for else condition */
}`

Answer (score 14):

there are two answers above, both got a lot acceptances:

1. str?.**let**{ } ?: run {  }
2. str?.**also**{ } ?: run {  }

Both seem to work in most of the usages, but #1 would fail in the following test:

[image]

#2 seems better.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Do not use variable?.let { doStuff() } ?: run { doOtherStuff() }
Because of doStuff returns null then the run block will also run. 
Also will return the value passed into the lambda so it will always return a value if there was a n on null value.

Answer (score 8):

Unlike Swift, Its not necessary to unwrap the optional before using it in Kotlin. We could just check if the value is non null and the compiler tracks the information about the check you performed and allows to use it as unwrapped.

In Swift:

```
if let a = b.val {
  //use "a" as unwrapped
} else {

}
```

In Kotlin:

```
if b.val != null {
  //use "b.val" as unwrapped
} else {

}
```

Refer [Documentation: (null-safety)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) for more such use cases

Comment: This only works if b is a local variable. What about class variables?

Comment: This totally doesn't apply in the general case (ie: when variables are class variables or are references from other classes. You really do need to create a snapshot copy of its variable and use that immutable value in the 'then' clause. Kotlin really needs this added to the language.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to only execute code when `name` is not null:

```
var name: String? = null
name?.let { nameUnwrapp ->
    println(nameUnwrapp)  // not printed because name was null
}
name = "Alex"
name?.let { nameUnwrapp ->
    println(nameUnwrapp)  // printed "Alex"
}
```

Comment: if name == null code in { } don't execute, if name as String - code execute : nameUnwrapp  == name.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking, I am sure OP already knows what `let` does, but the question is about the `else` strategy that executes if the object on which `let` is called is `null`. Swift has it in more natural (arguable) way. But having done both Kotlin and Swift a lot, I do wish Kotlin had a simple unwrapping like Swift does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my variant, limited to the very common "if not null" case.

First of all, define this somewhere:

```
inline fun <T> ifNotNull(obj: T?, block: (T) -> Unit) {
    if (obj != null) {
        block(obj)
    }
}
```

It should probably be `internal`, to avoid conflicts.

Now, convert this Swift code:

```swift
if let item = obj.item {
    doSomething(item)
}
```

To this Kotlin code:

```
ifNotNull(obj.item) { item -> 
    doSomething(item)
}
```

Note that as always with blocks in Kotlin, you can drop the argument and use `it`:

```
ifNotNull(obj.item) {
    doSomething(it)
}
```

But if the block is more than 1-2 lines, it's probably best to be explicit.

This is as similar to Swift as I could find.

Comment: the effort is good but you can't do if let else, thats why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I am very late however the easiest way to unwrap and option is

```
yourOptionalString ?: return
```

this was all the following lines will have unwrapped string

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to clarify the accepted answer because it's too big for a comment.

The general pattern here is that you can use any combination of the [Scope Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) available in Kotlin separated by the [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) like this:

```
<nullable>?.<scope function> {
    // code if not null
} :? <scope function> {
    // code if null
}
```

For example:

```
val gradedStudent = student?.apply {
    grade = newGrade
} :? with(newGrade) {
    Student().apply { grade = newGrade }
}
```

Comment: `let if` is used to make sure that you have a *non-null* value of your nullable variable, which is exactly what this solution does. And in a more efficient way because it doesn't create an extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest option in my opinion is this

Swift:

```
if let a = b.val {

} else {

}
```

Kotlin

```
b.val.also { a ->

} ?: run {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Swift if let statement in Kotlin

The short answer is use simple **IF-ELSE** as by the time of this comment there is no equivalent in Kotlin LET,

```
    if(A.isNull()){
// A is null
    }else{
// A is not null
    }
```

Comment: @JBarros35 correct, that is exactly what I said too lol, but I gave the next best option to what is available in the Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

we can get the same Unwraping syntax like Swift `if let` using `inline fun`

```
inline fun <T:Any?> T?.unwrap(callback: (T)-> Unit) : Boolean {
    return if (this != null) {
        this?.let(callback)
        true
    }else {
        false
    }
}
```

**Uses:** :

```
        val  name : String? = null
        val  rollNo : String? = ""
        var namesList: ArrayList<String>?  = null

        if (name.unwrap { name ->

                Log.i("Dhiru", "Name have value on it  $name")

            })else if ( rollNo.unwrap {
                Log.i("Dhiru","Roll have value on it")

            }) else if (namesList.unwrap {  namesList  ->
                Log.i("Dhiru","This is Called when names list have value ")
            })  {
             Log.i("Dhiru","No Field have value on it ")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `Any?.let {} ?: run {}` constructions is that:

- It only allows for one non-null check per statement
- If the `let` block returns null the run block is evaluated anyway
- It's not possible to perform multiple checks in a switch/when style

A solution which tackles most of these problems is to define functions like the following:

```
private inline fun <A> ifNotNull(p1: A?, block: (A) -> Unit): Unit? {
    if (p1 != null) {
        return block.invoke(p1)
    }
    return null
}

private inline fun <A, B> ifNotNull(p1: A?, p2: B?, block: (A, B) -> Unit): Unit? {
    if (p1 != null && p2 != null) {
        return block.invoke(p1, p2)
    }
    return null
}

private inline fun <A, B, C> ifNotNull(p1: A?, p2: B?, p3: C?, block: (A, B, C) -> Unit): Unit? {
    if (p1 != null && p2 != null && p3 != null) {
        return block.invoke(p1, p2, p3)
    }
    return null
}
```

This would allow for a statement like:

```
ifNotNull(a, b) { a, b ->
    // code when a, b are not null
} ?:
ifNotNull(c) { c ->
    // code when a, b are null and c not null
} ?: 
ifNotNull(d, e, f) { d, e, f ->
    // code when a, b, c are null and d, e, f not null
} ?: run {
    // code which should be performed if a, b, c, d, e and f are null
}
```

The only caveat is that `continue` and `break` statements are not supported if executed within a loop compared to Swift's `if let` equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

There is a similar way in kotlin to achieve Swift's style if-let

```
if (val a = b) {
    a.doFirst()
    a.doSecond()
}
```

You can also assigned multiple nullable values

```
if (val name = nullableName, val age = nullableAge) {
    doSomething(name, age)
}
```

This kind of approach will be more suitable if the nullable values is used for more than 1 times. In my opinion, it helps from the performance aspect because the nullable value will be checked only once.

source: [Kotlin Discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-null-check-for-multiple-nullable-vars/1946/22)

Comment: Please be aware that the approach you're showing does not compile currently. It is only a suggestion on how to alter the Kotlin language in order to deal with this issue. Hence, this is not a valid solution.

Answer (score -1):

If `b` is a member variable then this approach seems most readable to me:

```kotlin
val b = this.b
if (b == null) {
    return
}
println("non nullable : ${b}")
```

This is also consistent with how it works in swift, where a new local variable shadows the member variable.