# How to do guard let statement in Kotlin like Swift?

Tags: kotlin

I want to write guard let statement in Kotlin like Swift.

For example:

```swift
guard let e = email.text , !e.isEmpty else { return }
```

Any advice or sample code?

Comment: Is "guard let" like "if let"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723729/swift-if-let-statement-in-kotlin

Comment: yes, kind of :)

Comment: Then check that link. It may have an answer.

Comment: Please read [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). You used several tags that had different meanings (i.e. [tag:let] and [tag:guard]), and some that had nothing to do with the question (swift; don't tag source languages - the question is about Kotlin, not Swift)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try

```
val e = email.text?.let { it } ?: return
```

**Explanation**: This checks if the property `email.text` is not `null`. If it is not null, it assigns the value and moves to execute next statement. Else it executes the `return` statement and breaks from the method.

**Edit**: As suggested by @dyukha in the comment, you can remove the redundant `let`.

```
val e = email.text ?: return
```

If you want to check any other condition, you can use Kotlin's `if` expression.

```
val e = if (email.text.isEmpty()) return else email.text
```

Or try (as suggested by @Slaw).

```
val e = email.text.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: return
```

You may also like to try `guard` function as implemented here: https://github.com/idrougge/KotlinGuard

Comment: Why not just `email.text ?: return`?

Comment: Agreed @dyukha. Even sweeter!

Comment: But the condition in the question is different, isn't it? I don't quite understand what `guard let` does, but it seems that you should check that `email.text` is empty, not compare with null.

Comment: The `guard` swift statement is actually a glorified `if` statement.

 guard let name = nameField.text else {
        show("No name to submit")
        return
    }

Comment: I mean, in the question the condition is `!e.isEmpty`, not that `e` is not null.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191799/discussion-between-farhanjk-and-dyukha).

Comment: If you still want to use the elvis operator, you can use: `val e = email.text.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: return`.

Comment: I want to do something before return so what should I do ?

Comment: val e = email.text.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: print("this is not cool!").also { return }

Answer (score 30):

Try

```
val e = email.text ?: run {
    // do something, for example: Logging
    return@outerFunction
}
```

if you want to do something else before `return`.

Comment: It's the best answer but not perfect because let is useless. val e = email.text ?: run {
    // do something, for example: Logging
    return@outerFunction
}

Comment: looks promising syntax I have to try.

Comment: How do you capture exception in this case?

Comment: @mr5 what about
val e = runCatching{}.getOrNull()?: run {
    // do something
}

Answer (score 4):

I used this:

```
it ?: return
```

Simple and short

Comment: Note that this solution won't work for mutable fields like `email.text`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a slightly different solution, if you are looking to recreate the ability that swift has of unwrapping multiple optionals and then using the unwrapped variables.

consider adding these lines in a Kotlin file

```
    
    inline fun <T1, T2, T3, R> guard(
        p1: T1?, p2: T2?, p3: T3?,
        condition: Boolean = true,
        block: (T1, T2, T3) -> R
    ): R? = if (p1 != null && p2 != null && p3 != null && condition)
        block(p1, p2, p3)
    else null
    
    inline fun <T1, T2, T3, T4, R> guard(
        p1: T1?, p2: T2?, p3: T3?, p4: T4?,
        condition: Boolean = true,
        block: (T1, T2, T3, T4) -> R
    ): R? = if (p1 != null && p2 != null && p3 != null && p4 != null && condition)
        block(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    else null
```

(I did have up to p9 but saved it for brevity)

this means you do now do

```
    //given you have 

    var firstName: String? = null
    var lastName: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var password: String? = null
            
    fun createUser(name: String, lname: String, mail: String, pword: String) {
        // some work            
    }
```

you can now use it like this

```
    guard(firstName, lastName, email, password){ fName, lName, mail, pword ->            
        createUser(fName, lName, mail, pword) // all your variables are unwrapped!
    } ?: return // <- here if you want an early return

    // or
    guard(firstName, lastName, email, password,
        condition = email.isValid 
    ) { fName, lName, mail, pword -> 
        // N.B this will not execute if the email is not valid
        createUser(fName, lName, mail, pword)
    }
```

As this function is inlined you can use it in with coroutines and you can return a value from the `block` and use it.

Edit: I have put all the code in a gist here https://gist.github.com/markGilchrist/b699b00e9baeaa5e725a2eb1e9e7f5d3

Comment: Its rare I use something out of the box from here, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to do that. Simply create following function:

```kotlin
inline fun <T: Any> T?.guard(block: () -> Unit): T {
    if (this == null) block(); return this!!
}
```

Then you can use it like that:

```kotlin
val date: Date?
date = Date()
val nonNullableDate = date.guard { return }
```

`nonNullableDate` is then of type `Date`.

Anyway, as it is not during creation of a variable like in swift, `NullPointerExceptions` are possible **so make sure you exit the code part** with a `return` i.e.

Hopefully Kotlin is adding a `guard` keyword in the future.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/idrougge/KotlinGuard mentioned by @farhanjk is really cool, i extended it to also have an optional `condition` lambda:

```
inline fun <T : Any> T?.guard(
    noinline condition: ((T) -> Boolean)? = null,
    fail: () -> Nothing,
): T {
    this ?: fail()                      //ensure nonNull
    return if (condition == null) this  //not null and no condition present
    else {
        if (condition(this)) this       //condition present and satisfied
        else fail()                     //condition present but not satisfied
    }
}
```

This way, we can either only guard nullabililty:

```
val nullVariable: Int? = null
val nonNull: Int = nullVariable.guard {
    return Result.Error(..)
}
```

or also add a condition:

```
val myString: String? = ""
myString.guard({ it.isNotEmpty() }) {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("string not sufficient!")
}
```