# How to convert a nullable flowable to LiveData

Tags: kotlin

In my repository class I am calling webservice. If query is not null then returning the result as flowable, if query is null then return null . Then in my ViewModel I am converting the flowable to LiveData.

Below is the code snippet:

**In myRepository class:**

```
fun fetchToDosFromServer(fullQueryString: String?)
        : Flowable<GitResult>? 
{
    if(fullQueryString.length>0)
    { //call webservice- which return observable<GitResult>
       var returnedResult = myWebServiceCall()
        return returnedData.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
       }

    else 
        return null

}
```

**In myViewModel class:**

```
 fun getReposFromServer()
 {
    val resultFromApiCall_flowable : Flowable<GitResult>? =  mainRepository.fetchToDosFromServer("q=2")

    val source: LiveData<GitResult> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(resultFromApiCall_flowable)
 }
```

but its showing compile time error when trying to convert flowable to LiveData in myViewModel class. In the line:

> LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(resultFromApiCall_flowable)

the error is:

> Error: required Flowable , found Flowable?

how do I solve it?

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher : doen't work

Comment: `val resultFromApiCall_flowable : Flowable<GitResult>? =  mainRepository.fetchToDosFromServer("q=2")` is optional. So you can force cast with a `val resultFromApiCall_flowable : Flowable<GitResult>! = ..` Or you make a null check.

`resultFromApiCall_flowable?.let { 
 val source: LiveData<GitResult> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it)
}`

Comment: @kuzdu : I used the second option and it worked. thanks. But i have another confusion.. if I use `if(resultFromApiCall_flowable!=null)
  { val source: LiveData<GitResult> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(resultFromApiCall_flowable) }` then the error goes away too. But is it same as `xx?.let{...}`

Comment: It is, but you can handle `else` more conveniently here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got an answer how to handle it directly, but I suggest considering a different direction. Simply don't make the result nullable, and return `Flowable.empty()` in that case instead. And maybe don't accept `String?` either; do you actually want to call `fetchToDosFromServer(null)` in some cases?

Comment: if I return `Flowable.empty()` then how do I check when its returned empty?

Comment: In most cases you don't want to check; just treat it as any other returned `Flowable`. If you do want to distinguish this situation, this isn't a good solution. But why treat `fetchToDosFromServer("")` differently from `fetchToDosFromServer(anyInvalidQueryString)`?

Comment: Of course, this suggests returning `Flowable.error()` or throwing an exception instead of `Flowable.empty()`; whatever `fetchToDosFromServer` does for invalid query strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow is optional.

So if you make a null check it should work.

```
val resultFromApiCall_flowable: Flowable<GitResult>? = mainRepository.fetchToDosFromServer("q=2")

if (resultFromApiCall_flowable != null) {
 val source: LiveData<GitResult> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(resultFromApiCall_flowable)
}
```

This is the same like

```
resultFromApiCall_flowable?.let { 
 val source: LiveData<GitResult> = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it)
}
```

Anyway, you can use both, but it is not the same.

Have a look here: [let vs if not null](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/let-vs-if-not-null/3542)

If you like to handle the `else` case:

```
b?.let {
    // If b is not null.
} ?: run {
    // If b is null.
}
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/46726337/4420355 by marstran