# Pass no value to function with default parameters

Tags: kotlin, default-value

I have this Kotlin function:

```
fun doSomething(user: User = defaultUser) {
  //do something
}
```

and I call it from another place:

```
val user: User? = getUser()
if (user == null) {
  doSomething()
} else {
  doSomething(user)
}
```

Is it possible to improve this code? I think this "if/else" is a little bit messy. Is possible to do something like this?

`doSomething(user ?: NoValue)`

Comment: how's that different from `doSomething(user ?: defaultUser)` ?

Comment: Problem is I'm calling 'doSomething` function from a class that doesn't know (and it shouldn't) the default user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cut it down to `user?.run(::doSomething) ?: doSomething()` (if `doSomething` doesn't return null) but I don't know why you'd want to!

Honestly the if/else reads nice to me, stick it on one line without the braces and it's nice and compact. Unfortunately I don't think you can conditionally add parameters into a function call (and handling default parameters can get unnwieldy when you have a few).

I agree with @benjiii, it might be better to have a nullable parameter and handle the default internally, if you don't need to use null as a legit value

Comment: `if (user == null) doSomething() else doSomething(user)` for people that prefer code instead of words

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
getUser()?.let { // user is not null
  doSomething(it)
} ?: run { // user is null here
  doSomething()
}
```

(cf: [Swift 'if let' statement equivalent in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723729/swift-if-let-statement-equivalent-in-kotlin))

<s>I don't think you could do something shorter without making the code hard to understand</s> Edit 2: Actually you can, see the comment

Edit: I would personally handle the nullable variable inside the function like this:

```
fun doSomething(user: User?) {
  val correctUser = user ?: defaultUser
  //do something
}
```

so you can use the function like this:

```
doSomething(getUser())
```

Comment: `getUser()?.let { doSomething(it) } ?: doSomething()` no need for `run`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with cactustictacs, just putting it on one line is clear and simple. However, if you use it often and it's bothering you, it's easy enough to wrap it in a function without the default parameter:

```
fun doSomethingSensibly(user: User?) =
    if (user == null)
        doSomething()
    else
        doSomething(user)
```

Which can be used as:

```
doSomethingSensibly(getUser())
```